# How do I solve an io.netty error in my testing project

Tags: java, netty

I am setting up a back-end test using Java.
When running my test I am presented with the following error:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateUninitializedArray(I)[B**

My pom file contains the following dependencies in regard to Netty:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.36.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code itself looks as follows:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient;
import org.mockserver.matchers.Times;
import org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest;
import org.mockserver.model.HttpResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PdfGenerateStep {

    @Autowired
    private MockServerClient mockServerClient;

    @And("Pdf {string} is generated")
    public void generatePDF(String pdfFile) {

        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        httpRequest.withPath("/pdf-service/doc/request")
            .withHeader("template", "TEST")
            .withHeader("docFormat", "pdf")
            .withHeader("fromParty", "PDFGEN")
            .withHeader("APPLICATION", "App")
            .withMethod("POST");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse();
        httpResponse.withStatusCode(200);
        httpResponse.withBody(readPdfFile(pdfFile));

        mockServerClient.when(httpRequest, Times.once()).respond(httpResponse);
    }

    private byte[] readPdfFile(String file) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file).toURI());

            return Files.readAllBytes(path);

        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: That is typically an indication of mismatching versions. One library X assumes library Y is present in verison a.b.c. But Y actually has an older (or maybe incompatible) newer version. In other words: that dependency that actually uses netty probably wants **another** netty version. I would start with: trying latest greatest 4.1.42 ... or maybe an older one, like 4.0.56.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no allocateUninitializedArray method in io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent class, so in your classpath there is an another jar that contains this class, but **the version, and therefore the code of this class will be different**.

The io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent class can be found in netty-common, which is a transitive dependency of netty-transport.

So, check the dependency tree of your project.
Very probably you have an another dependency that has a different version of netty-common as a transitive dependency.
Exclude the wrong one and you will be done.

Comment: I used maven helper plugin to track down and exclude the conflicting dependencies.
Works fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

add this dependency in your pom.xml file.